# How can I query data by _id in mongotemplate

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Id
@Field("_id")
private String          id;
```

This is my eneity. And when I query by id,  the result alway is null.

```
    final Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("_id").is(testPlanInfo.getId());

    final TestPlan testPlan = MongodbUtils.findOne(criteria, TestPlan.class);
    if (testPlan == null) {
        throw new CustomException("testplan.unknownTestPlan");
    }
```

And I confirm the testPlanInfo.getId() is same as the _id in mongodb doc.

Comment: The MongoUtils is same as mongoTemplate,

Comment: And the spring boot version is 2.2.9

Comment: can you show us your model class

Comment: It is probably because you will have ObjectId in mongo and you are using string in Java. wrap ```testPlanInfo.getId()``` inside ```org.bson.types.ObjectId``` constructor and you will get result